# To list the records from a Linq query using the model class in API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In API controller, I am trying to map manually author's list of article to the corresponding modelDTO. I am using the model class AuthorDTO and NewsContentDTO to list author details and his corresponding articles. Looking for someone help to map all NewContents of an author from linq result to AuthorDTO and to return AuthorDTO with the details of an author and  its corresponding all news contents. How can I poppulate NewsContents in  AuthorDTO from the result coming from GetHeroAuthor()

```
public class AuthorDTO
    {                 
            public int Id { get; set; }          
            public string FirstName { get; set; }           
            public string LastName { get; set; }             
            public List<NewsContentDTO> NewsContents { get; set; }
    }

public class NewsContentDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string ContentTitle { get; set; }         
        public AuthorDTO Author { get; set; }
    }
```

In API controller

```
 var authors = _authorRepo.GetHeroAuthor();

            AuthorDTO author = new AuthorDTO()
            {
                FirstName = authors.FirstName,
                LastName = authors.LastName
                NewsContents = New List<NewsContentDTO>() 
                {
                  Category  = authors.NewsContents.Category,
                  ContentTitle = authors.NewsContents.ContentTitle
                }
                
            };

return(author);
```

List of Records is coming from repo

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "My",
    "lastName": "Name",   
    "newsContents": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category": "Story",
            "contentTitle": "Shopping Trip",             
        },
     {
            "id": 3,
            "category": "Story",
            "contentTitle": "Rainy day",             
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You could try with C#  reflection or just try as authors.NewsContents.Select(x => new NewsContentDTO(), to poppulate NewsContents in AuthorDTO,which way do you prefer and whats the problem you are facing with?

Answer (score 0):

As you've not explicitly provided a question I presume your challenge is mapping a list of subitems.

```
AuthorDTO author = new AuthorDTO()
{
    FirstName = authors.FirstName,
    LastName = authors.LastName
    // THIS WON'T WORK
    NewsContents = New List<NewsContentDTO>() 
    {
        Category  = authors.NewsContents.Category,
        ContentTitle = authors.NewsContents.ContentTitle
    }
    // TO MAP A SOURCE LIST TO TARGET LIST, TRY THIS ...
    NewsContents = authors.NewsContents.Select(nc => new NewsContentDTO()
    {
        Category = nc.Category,
        ContentTitle = nc.ContentTitle
    }).ToList();
};
```